# How to avoid keyboard block screen using scroll view (using adjustResize)

Tags: android, android-layout, window-soft-input-mode

My question may be [duplicate] i try all solutions but nothing work.

[image: Scroll full down and its not show bottom of scroll view]

[image: Its Image without keyboard full scroll down]

Activity declare in manifest 
I am using adjustResize but its not work . i try adjustPan and other option but no one works.

```
     <activity
        android:name=".NotesActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
```

XML screen code
I am using scroll view but still cant prevent screen blockage .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<View
    android:id="@+id/sep"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/colorwhite" />


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sep"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Medical Certificate Issued:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme3">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_yes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:checked="true"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="No"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/certificate_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="25dp"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/certificate_from"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="From"
                android:textColor="@color/colorblack" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/certificate_to"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="To"
                android:textColor="@color/colorblack" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Follow up required:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme3">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_follow_yes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_follow_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="No"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_sc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="SC"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_p"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="P"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_pt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:ems="3"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="PT"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_rfb"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="RFB"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_path"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="PATH"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_ref"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorblack"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="REF"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme3" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edit"
                android:text="Your Signature:"
                android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/remove"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_line"
                android:ems="5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="Remove"
                android:textColor="@color/colorwhite" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/remove"
                android:background="@drawable/round_line"
                android:ems="5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="Edit"
                android:textColor="@color/colorwhite" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edittext">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minLines="7"
                android:text="Add your signature!"
                android:textColor="@color/colorblack"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/signature_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/add"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/add"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/add"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/add" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `alignParentBottom` to your `ScrollView`. So when your parent will be stretched, the `ScrollView` will follow and be stretched as well. Let me know if that works!

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sep"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">
```

Comment: You should try removing fillViewPort on the ScrollView & removing fitsSystemWindows on the parent... It's seems that you kept many fix that weren't working there...

Comment: just removed fillViewPort  on the ScrollView & removing fitsSystemWindows. But still not working.   Yes i try many things but not worked

Comment: But can you scroll? What are you trying to achieve here? You want to keep seeing the submit button?

Comment: When keyboard is open i can't see signature part even full scroll

Comment: We are missing an information here probably... Did you put  `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` in the App style? Because that cancel the AdjustResize attribute. Also, I don't use ->  `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in my Activity that look like yours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128186/discussion-between-rizwan-ahmed-and-jaythaking).

Answer (score 0):

i use just

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

and it works in my applications